# Life Tables in R using StMoMo package

Tags: r

I have mortality data from HMD and I used StMoMo package for the fitting and forecasting. One of the models I use is the Renshaw-Haberman. My code is:

```
ages.fit<-55:89
wxt<- genWeightMat(ages = 55:89, years = grstomo.male$years, clip = 3)
rh<-rh(link = "log", cohortAgeFun = "1")
rhfit.male<- fit(rh, data = grstomo.male, ages.fit = ages.fit, wxt=wxt)
```

Do you know how i can create a life table from this model?

Thank you